# getting error in month.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH) == month.getActualMaximum(GregorianCalendar.MONTH)

Tags: android

I was trying to implement the Calendar adapter in one of my project. It worked fine earlier in eclipse. But when i import the project to Android Studio i am getting error in this line :

```
 if (month.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH) == 
      month.getActualMaximum(GregorianCalendar.MONTH))
```

For `month.getActualMaximum(GregorianCalendar.MONTH)` it says it should be something `Calendar.MONDAY` or `Calendar.SUNDAY` etc. I cant understand this error. It was working fine earlier.

Answer (score 0):

To change your codes declaration and checking as separately like this

```
  if (month.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH) == 
  month.getActualMaximum(GregorianCalendar.MONTH))
```

this is your code and write it like

```
  int a=month.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH);
  int b=month.getActualMaximum(GregorianCalendar.MONTH);
  if (a==b){
  //do your stuff here
  }
```

Thank you